# Symbolic links for directories

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

Really need a  quick help on this. This is the scenario. 
Created source directory 
`SOURCE :`
`/apps/application_scripts/intl/bin`

Here I have lot of shell scripts (*.sh)

`TARGET :`
`/home/edwprod/intl/bin`


Symbolic link:
`ln -s /apps/application_scripts/intl/bin /home/edwprod/intl/bin`

If i execute some ksh like this in some other directory 
`/home/edwprod/intl/bin/ex1.sh`

It shows the error message
`not found [No such file or directory]`

Please advice.

Comment: Do you have the appropriate File Access Permissions(FAP) to the script file?

Comment: Does `/home/edwprod/intl/bin` exist prior to your `ln -s` command?

Comment: yes.. it exists already..due to space issue . i am moving to /apps path and providing symbolic links

Comment: @AruM: Like with `cp`, if the second argument of `ln -s` is existing directory, the link is created *in* the directory with name given by last component of the link target, so you probably have `/home/edwprod/intl/bin/bin` now.

Comment: Yes great. I found this,but how do i correct this. Help me as this is urgent.

Comment: Save whatever is important in /home/edwprod/intl/bin in a safe location, then `rm -rf /home/edwprod/intl/bin`. finally run your `ln -s` command.

Comment: You should do ln -s `/apps/application_scripts/intl/bin/* /home/edwprod/intl/bin` if I guess your intention correctly

Answer (score 0):

Please try that:

```
cd /home/edwprod/intl/
mv bin  old-bin
ln -s /apps/application_scripts/intl/bin .
ls -l bin bin/
```

What does it display?